# protobuf will not compile on osx when using g++-5

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, protocol-buffers

See the following sample project based on the [c++ tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) on [protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf).

https://github.com/cskeeters/protobuf_addressbook

I installed protobuf on osx 10.10.5 using:

`brew install protobuf`

I installed g++-5 via brew install also, but it's been a while.  Why won't this won't compile with g++?

The command that fails is:

`g++-5  -g -O2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/2.6.1/lib -lprotobuf -D_THREAD_SAFE   -o main main.o addressbook.pb.o`

The result is:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedFile(char const*, void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&))", referenced from:
      tutorial::protobuf_AddDesc_addressbook_2eproto()      in addressbook.pb.o
...`

I'm just testing.  I have no reason not to use clang++ on osx.  I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because different ABI for clang, g++-5 and g++-4.x. You need first to recompile protobuf itself with g++-5, and only then link it to your program with `-lprotobuf`.

Comment: I have verified that g++-5 can be used when protobuf is compiled with g++-5.  I had to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to get the resulting binary to utilize the non-brew library.